# TensorBoard link won't load TensorFlow graphs page in browser (The connection was reset)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have created a visualization.py file that is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
a = tf.add(1, 2,)
b = tf.multiply(a, 3)
c = tf.add(4, 5,)
d = tf.multiply(c, 6,)
e = tf.multiply(4, 5,)
f = tf.div(c, 6,)
g = tf.add(b, d)
h = tf.multiply(g, f)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("output", sess.graph)
    print(sess.run(h))
    writer.close()
```

When I run this in command prompt it creates the 'output' folder in my current directory, '[Andrews-MacBook-Pro]: ~/coding/tensorflow/learningtensorflow/Visualization'

I then enter the following into command prompt:

```
tensorboard --logdir=output
```

the output is:

```
TensorBoard 1.5.0 at http://Andrews-MacBook-Pro.local:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When I enter http://Andrews-MacBook-Pro.local:6006 in browser it leads to the connection was reset page (I am using Firefox/MacOS but also have the same issue in Chrome).  How can I properly access the Tensorflow graphs page?

Comment: Is it possible you need to use `tensorboard --logdir=/coding/tensorflow/learningtensorflow/Visualization/output`?

Comment: Unfortunately it still leads to a 'Connection was reset page'.  Weirdly, if I enter **0.0.0.0:6006** into the browser, it properly connects me to the graphs TF page.  Still I wonder why the given link from the TF command prompt won't function properly?

Comment: This thread also led me to a better understanding of the issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/89

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, just add --host=0.0.0.0

```
tensorboard --logdir=output --host=0.0.0.0
```

output

```
TensorBoard 1.10.0 at http://0.0.0.0:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

This should solve your problem!